# Why CGi scripts do not read headers from STDIN

Tags: webserver, cgi, fastcgi

Following recent vulnerabilities related to CGI, I read a little about it and have a question. Please note that I've never used CGI myself and that I don't code in PHP or Perl, so there maybe something obvious that I'm missing.

As I understand, the response message must be written by the script to STDOUT including *both* headers and body. Why then not read the whole request message from STDIN including both headers and body? Why headers are stripped out and assigned to environmental variables instead?

Answer (score 0):

Response messages to Stdout only contain any additional headers that the CGI wishes to add.  These may be replaced or altered by the host web service before they are emitted to the client.  Also other headers will be added in general.

As for incoming headers, it makes absolutely no sense to put the burden and risk of parsing these onto the CGI.  Parsing errors create all sorts of vulnerabilities.  The Web server host is the best thing to do this.

However with FastCGI it's different again, since environment variables are no longer an option, since the CGI process stays resident.

Comment: I mean that the parsing of incoming message should be done by the ultimate program (written in C, perl or whatever). How is this less secure than setting environmental variables?

Comment: the reason, is every different CGI would need to have its own parser code for this.  It's better from the server point of view if it does the parsing itself, then it doesn't open itself up to exploits of poorly written CGIs with parsing bugs.

Comment: And btw, parsing of a POST body is left to the program itself, so if it parses body anyway, why not parse the whole message

Comment: that's true, but also there's the legacy problem.  The CGI interface has the host parse the headers.  You'd have to manage compatibility issues if you were to get the CGI to parse request headers.  My point about emitted response headers is also pertinent.  A script can break a lot of things (framing etc) by emitting bad headers.  A server will always have the option to vet emitted headers, and the server has the responsibility to ensure that the response is well-formed, and contains any necessary headers that may have been omitted by the script.